# Blender 2.8 render farm on DL380 Gen9 w/ Virtual Shared Graphics Acceleration

Tags: rendering, opengl

We're looking to upgrade our render farm from 2.79 to 2.80 using a Tesla M10, Quadro P6000, or Quadro RTX6000 and enabling Virtual Shared Graphics Acceleration on DL380 Gen9 – We're trying to meet the OpenGL 3.3+ requirement in particular and this would utilize VMware’s 3D driver, which does have support for OpenGL, but would need to be certified by Blender if it is not already. I searched Blender’s site but could not find anything regarding the certification of VMware’s driver. Would Blender devs be able to comment/answer or is this more appropriately directed at HPE/VMWare?

Comment: As far as I'm aware Blender doesn't certify any drivers. The official drivers by Nvidia and AMD is what's generally supported. I'm not sure if the Virtual Shared Pass-Through Graphics Acceleration is enough to get CUDA running properly for GPU rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to ask the developers at the Blender Organization to see if that driver could be used on the program.